# Wake computer from sleep/standby without BIOS support for WOL?

Tags: networking, power-management, wake-on-lan, wake-up

Just bought a new home PC and the nice folks at HP disabled the Wake-On-Lan feature in my motherboard.

Are there any other options for waking the computer from Sleep/Standby mode? I'd like to take advantage of power savings wherever I can.

I realize that I won't be able to wake it from shutdown, short of putting together some Rube Goldberg machine.

EDIT: I'd like to be able to wake the machine on demand, remotely. So I can then RDP into it, or access files, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to rig up a solution using my router with DD-WRT installed.

The computer will wake up from standby if it receives a "magic packet" from the LAN, so I've configured SSH on the router, and I just run a script that will SSH into the router and then execute the wake-on-lan script from the router interface.

I created a variation of this script: [DD-WRT Useful Scripts](http://secure.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Useful_Scripts#Web_Server_Wake-up)

Comment: This will not work for the OP, since his mobo does not support WOL. You basically just described how WOL works on a router.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Task Scheduler to wake the computer.

1. Click Start, type **Task Scheduler** in the Start Search box, and then click **Task Scheduler** in the Programs list.

*If you are prompted for an administrator password or for confirmation, type your password, or click Continue.*

2. In the Actions pane of the Task Scheduler dialog box, click **Create Task**.
3. In the Create Task dialog box, click the **Conditions** tab.
4. Click to select the **Wake the computer to run this task** check box.
5. In the Create Task dialog box, configure the options on the other tabs as appropriate for your needs, and then click OK.

Comment: I'd like to be able to wake the computer on-demand, remotely.

Comment: Ah, well that really changes things. How about flashing the BIOS?

Comment: No BIOS updates available.

Answer (score 1):

You could always buy another network card that has a Wake on Lan feature? Short of that, I am not to sure.

...I am guessing from your subject, that is all you are interested in - not just normally coming out of sleep by moving the mouse/keyboard.

Comment: I don't think the NIC is the issue, it supports Wake On Lan, and has all the options available for it. My issue is my BIOS/Motherboard doesn't support it, and I can't afford to replace the motherboard for this small inconvenience.

Comment: The motherboard is an Asus, Motherboard Name: IPIBL-LB, HP/Compaq motherboard name: Benicia-GL8E. I read somewhere that the Asus motherboard supports it, but HP disabled the feature so they wouldn't have to support it.

Comment: if the mainboard does not support WOL, another NIC won't help much. NIC will send signal to mainboard where it will be met by ignorance. :)

Comment: @Molly, I am talking about a "Real" WOL card, they generally have a chip with a cable coming out that goes straight to the 2x10 power connector where it passes through the power - but upon WOL it "emulates" power on... I can't find quickly, but this is very similar - https://www.jcl.co.uk/acatalog/tokenpci.jpg  @Jjeaton, If the NIC supports it, but HP has disabled it, I find that very weird - try to reflash the BIOS with the stock ASUS firmware and it should remove any/all limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the nature of the WHS Box, and specifically the HP Server version, this is not supported. The HP WHS server uses very little power, since it is designed to be a always on media streaming device first and foremost. I have a custom WHS server I built and have yet to see a dent in my electricity bill.

Another reason  it is disabled is becuase of the autometed process and backup processes it runs, again if you use the functionality. I use it for both Mac Time Machine backups and backing up Windows Machines, which normally happens when these machines are idle. Also WHS can remotely wake your PC to fire these processes if required.

It seems that you are trying to do something with WHS that it is not designed for. I just confirmed on my copy of WHS that this feature is also disabled in WHS directly, so it is not specific to HP, but the way the OS in this case has been designed.

Comment: This isn't a WHS box. I shouldn't have called it a "home server" it's just a desktop PC that I'm using as a media server.